# Send output from SSRS as PDF direct to printer

Tags: c#, printing, ssrs-2008

I am trying to get the out put from SSRS export and send it direct to a Server side printer without calling a print Dialog

```
ReportingService.ReportExporter.Export("basicHttpEndpoint", new NetworkCredential("userNmae", "*********"), reportName, parameters.ToArray(), reportFormat, out output, out extension, out mimeType, out encoding, out warnings, out streamIds);
```

In this case the export type is an Image; I am trying to get the output (which is a Byte Array) and setting a Memory stream and then trying  to print directly using `PrintDocumen()` as follows

```
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(output);
StreamReader streamToPrint = new StreamReader(stream);

var pd = new PrintDocument();
pd.PrintPage += pd_PrintPage;
pd.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
pd.Print();
```

The `pd_PrintPage` is well documented onthe web and MSDN

```
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
{
  float linesPerPage = 0;
  float yPos = 0;
  int count = 0;
  float leftMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Left;
  float topMargin = ev.MarginBounds.Top;
  string line = null;

  // Calculate the number of lines per page.
  linesPerPage = ev.MarginBounds.Height /
     printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics);

  // Print each line of the file. 
  while (count < linesPerPage &&
     ((line = streamToPrint.ReadLine()) != null))
  {
      yPos = topMargin + (count *
         printFont.GetHeight(ev.Graphics));
      ev.Graphics.DrawString(line, printFont, Brushes.Black,
         leftMargin, yPos, new StringFormat());
      count++;
  }

  // If more lines exist, print another page. 
  if (line != null)
      ev.HasMorePages = true;
  else
      ev.HasMorePages = false;
}
```

I am not able to get the format of the data, it just prints the image data as characters. DO I need to convert the output data to another format?

Answer (score 0):

Becasue you're telling the print command to brint the bytes as text instead of *rendering* the output.  In order to render the stream to the printer you need a PDF print driver (e.g. Acrobat).  Here are some options:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8338953/print-in-memory-pdf-without-saving-directly-without-a-printer-dialog-or-user-i

[Printing a PDF in c# using a stream ... can it be done ?](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/591589-printing-pdf-c-using-stream-can-done)